# How can I disable overlayroot via ssh?

Tags: server, grub2, ssh

I have a remote computer protected with overlayroot. Currently, I write "overlayroot=disabled" in grub boot to disable it until it is rebooted, but sometimes I want to make changes using SSH. Is there a way to disable overlayroot remotely?

Comment: The only way that I am aware of that you would be able to do that is to have some sort of serial console connection to the host that can monitor a reboot like how server hardware will have a management console connection through the network that is on a different IP that will allow you to monitor and fix a reboot.  Other than that, the OS would be protected until you reboot and since you are not physically there it would be impossible to adjust the grub menu remotely during a reboot.

Comment: This might help: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/#comment-585708

Answer (score 2):

You can run [`overlayroot-chroot`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/overlayroot-chroot.8.html) to remount the root as rw, or [bind-mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/77489)  the lowerdir elsewhere as rw with something like `mount --bind <lowerdir> /mnt/rootrw` and modify on `/mnt/rootrw` (potentially chrooting to it if needed).

Check [the link @Melebius gave](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/#comment-585708), it (at least partially) answers the question.

Comment: So, the `overlayroot-chroot` *(worth noting that the name in the post should be fixed)* works for me. However, the `mount` command didn't: I did `mount | grep lowerdir`, and dir turned out to be `/media/root-ro`. Then I executed `mount -o remount,rw /media/root-ro`, but upon reboot all changes to the system are gone. So the idea with remounting doesn't work.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thanks, I fixed the typo. For the "mount" option, I guess changes were lost because they were made in the upperdir: even though the lowerdir is mounted rw, if a file exists in both upper anb lower, the upper one will be used (and modified); and if the upperdir is not persisted (e.g. in tmpfs), its changes will be lost upon reboot.
Anyway, the way to do it is with `overlayroot-chroot` indeed; the mount thing is kind of hacky...

Comment: Could you please provide a working example for disabling overlayroot on Ubuntu using overlayroot-chroot command?

Comment: @AhmedEissa where are you stuck? `sudo overlayroot-chroot` pretty much gives you a shell in the lower dir mounted rw...

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this is as follows.  It involves several reboots to bring the system up rw then back to ro once again.

1. SSH into the system and enter a rw chroot via the following command:
   `sudo overlayroot-chroot`
2. Modify the /etc/overlayroot.local.conf (docs mention that you should create a .local. rather than the default overlayroot.conf file to avoid conflict if overlayroot package ever gets updated.) `overlayroot=""`
3. Reboot, system is now mounted rw, make changes to system.  edit /etc/overlayroot.local.conf overlayroot= line back to the enabled
   value (in my case: `overlayroot="tmpfs:swap=1,recurse=0"`).
4. Reboot again, system is once again read-only.